# How do I apply css to firefox extension elements?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to style different elements of my firefox extension. This is how I include css:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/sidebar.css" type"text/css" ?>
```

E.g. I want to change the color of the

```
<tab label="Start"/>
```

elements.

I set

```
tab{
 color:red;
}
```

but it is not working. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: You have to reference the CSS file of your extension... I don't think your extension's name is `global`. Should be something along the lines of `chrome://yourextensionsname/skin/sidebar.css`.

Comment: thanks, that actually was my problem. you could post this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference the CSS file of your extension... I don't think your extension's name is global.

Should be something along the lines of `chrome://yourextensionsname/skin/sidebar.css`

Comment: And just in case your extension's name IS global, you should definitely change it!